# Magento Product Attributes index process unknown error after importing multiselect attribute

Tags: magento, import, attributes, multi-select, reindex

After importing a multiselect product attribute, when I try to reindex from magento admin the indexer shows error.         **"There was a problem with reindexing process."**

Exception log :

```
2012-12-05T12:21:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '185-154-1-843' for key 'PRIMARY'
Trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(239): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1974): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(276): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_saveIndexData(Array)
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(84): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareMultiselectIndex(NULL, NULL)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(50): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareIndex()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mise/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

The product import file contains only 2 columns sku and attribute value

Also I tried manual import using custom php code. Same error...!!!

I think 185 in '185-154-1-843' is product id. So i went admin and just saved the product and error for that product solved but it shows duplicate entry for another product. :(

please help

Comment: Try deleting the product in admin with id 185 and importing again,as it shows : Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '185-154-1-843' for key 'PRIMARY'    means there are duplicated product ids.

Comment: deleted the product. But it shows error for another row :)

Comment: Do you get the same error??

Comment: [There are well explained](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/product-attributes-could-not-be-reindexed) this problem

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

Try deleting the product in admin with `id 185` and importing again, as it shows:

`Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 
Duplicate entry '185-154-1-843' for key 'PRIMARY'`

which means that there are duplicated product ids.

Just keep deleting the error ids.

Comment: Bytheway anyone knows what is actual reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. You can do something else than deleting the product :

We solved this by editing attribute which was a multiselect and inside this array of values, we had 2 times the same value!

> If it occurs to someone else, just look at the attribute's value,
>   merge siblings by removing double value and it might solve your issue.

On my case we could see that by selecting our product id ( first value inside the error duplicate entry) and having a look to the attribute mentionned ( second value in error)